# Best language to use for an online dictionary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, dictionary

I just wanted to know what language you think would be best to build an online dictionary. I would like users to be able to search for words and return the meaning and so on. I also want to be able to allow users to sign in and be able to favorite words and that will be added to their own personal list of words which they can view on a separate list of favorited words. Before everyone tells me that there are many online dictionaries, I am doing this for my native language, Chamorro, which has almost no online resources or translations.

Also, I was thinking of using Ruby on Rails as I already know how to build an application with users, but i have no idea how to query a database.

Any help will do, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any language would accomplish your task.  Which you use is entirely up to you.  My recommendation would be to use the language you know best.  If that's Ruby on Rails great.  If it's Python great.

I can't think of anything about your project that is unique enough to require a specific language choice.

Answer (score 1):

The best language in any situation is the one that you know how to use effectively to solve your problem.

Some languages do have features that are specific enough to warrant use in certain situations, but those are generally highly advanced topics.